# How do I create a facebook app to run a contest on an existing fan page?

Tags: facebook-page

Okay, I thought I had a pretty good understanding of Facebook until I got into the realm of apps.  I already have a fan page, but want to be able to run contests with my fans.  I just read on the FB rules that you have to run contests through apps.  So, I went to the facebook developer site and got one started.  However, I'm confused.  Am I creating a new fan page and will have to start all over again with acquiring fans or can I just link this to my current fan page someone and run my contests off of this "page/link" on my fan page.

I want to be able to run contests (in accordance with FB rules and regulations) from my fan page.  Can someone please explain how this is done through apps.  Also, if you have examples of what these apps look like please post so that I can check them out to help my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

According to the guidelines you can just create a fan page tab, which is basically an app.  Here is a good tutorial on creating an [iframe page tab](http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/adding-iframe-application-to-facebook-fan-page/).  You will need a public webserver to deploy this too and soon you will need an SSL certificate for your domain so it can be browsed by people that have enabled SSL on their Facebook account.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your contest on a Iframe Tab and add the Tab to your Page.

Here you can read the guide
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/